# Why in xna 4.0 i don't have the Content directory in the project?

Tags: c#, .net, xna, xna-4.0

On the right in the screenshot i uploaded no Content there is Content References but right click on it dosent have the Add > File Exit...

I want to load the files on the left grass and path
I have them in my project directory:

C:\test\test\testcontent
And there is another directory there:

C:\test\test\test\bin\x86\debug\Content

Tried to put the images in both directories when i'm running my program i'm getting error the file grass not found.
Tried in my project right click and add existing item but it didn't work.

[image: No Content Directory]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's something wrong with your solution.
There must be two projects: one is your game project and one is game content project.
See [this link](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/managing-content) for more info.

Maybe you trying open with xna 4.0 old project (xna 3.5)?

Comment: Silveor yes i see now two projects. But why if i make in visual studio New > Project > Xna 4.0 studio > Windows Game it's not making new clean solution but adding a new project to the exisiting already solution ? In c# when i did new project winforms it allways did a new solution clean project.

Comment: When i make new project for xna i see in Solution: Create new Solution and create new directory for oslution is marked.

Comment: 4.0 does that sometimes you need to add a project yourself and setup the content pipeline stuff in there. You might be able to fix that by reinstalling xna from creators website

Comment: Also i see now on my project name there is a yeelow small triangle with a question sign inside "?"